# Norm equivalency

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose there are two norms on a Banach Space: (X, $||•||_1$) and (X, $||•||_2$) where, for any sequence {$x_n$} in X, $||x_n||_1$->0 implies $||x_n||_2$->0. Show that these norms are equivalent.

I'm fairly certain that making an identity between (X, $||•||_1$) and (X, $||•||_2$) is a reasonable start to this problem. From there, the closed graph theorem and bounded inverse theorem are likely used (since they are introduced in the same section as this exercise) although I'm not really sure as to how each are used.

Let the identity mapping mentioned above be T, then I know that with X being complete, we have that T is closed (unless my knowledge of the closed graph theorem is mistaken). Also, the bounded inverse theorem would imply that if T is bounded linear and bijective then it's inverse is also bounded. The bounded was would likely be helpful with showing equivalency.

The details I'm unsure of: is T bounded? How does closure of T come into play? How does the assumption of convergence to 0 in norm take part in this argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First show, using the sequence condition that $\Vert x\Vert_2 \leq c\Vert x\Vert_1$ for some $c>0$. Then, we have that the identity map $$I:X_1 \rightarrow X_2$$ is a bounded linear bijection between Banach spaces. Open mapping theorem (bounded inverse) says its inverse is also bounded...

Comment: That's pretty straightforward. think that I see how to finish from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could work by contradiction and assume the two norms are not equivalent, that one is unbounded with respect to the other. Then you can find a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $||x_n||_1 \leq c$ (with $c$ a positive constant) and $||x_n||_2 \geq n$ $\forall n$. Now the sequence $y_n = x_n/ \sqrt n$ clearly converges to $0$ in the first norm and diverges in the other, so that if the norms are not equivalent you can always violate your hypothesis of implied convergence.

Comment: I like that argument although it doesn't capture the use of either bounded inverse theorem or the closed graph theorem. I'm trying to find a way to use those since they were brought up in the same section as this exercise.